# Caching data with class properties - why is it a bad idea?

Tags: php, performance, caching, scalability

I've recently been reading many articles on scalability for PHP apps. Nearly all of the articles I have read have mentioned caching, so I came up with this idea of caching DB data in class properties, to prevent excess DB queries. I wanted to share the idea so I blogged about it, only to have my teacher tell me it was pointless and silly. Apart from using the words pointless and silly, he couldn't really explain why it was bad. Could someone here please explain why this method of caching, to help scale PHP applications is bad?

**The method:**

Theory:

Instead of fetching the data in every method (where needed) from the DB, executing query after query, I thought it would be a good idea to have a class property (variable) that stores the fetched DB data, to prevent the need of duplicate queries or queries that will return the same data.

If you didn't get that, here's an example taken from my blog:

---

I'm going to bring Facebook into this example, just to ease the explanation a bit. Let's say we were re-coding the user class for the social network.

```
class FBuser
{

}
```

The obvious methods this class would contain:

```
getStatusUpdates()
getAccountInfo()
getFriendIDs()
```

Originally, those methods would each have to execute database queries, to get the required data. But with the caching method, I would define a class property to store the cached data, and would have all the DB querying going on in a single method:

```
class FBuser
{
    private $userCache = array();

    private function getData( $dataToGet = '' )
    {

    //all of my db querying would happen here

    }

}
```

But in that same method, I would also be looking for cache, if I'm allowed to do so:

```
private function getData( $dataToGet = '' , $useCache = true )
{
   //am I allowed to use cache?
   if ( $useCache === true )
   { 
       //does the appropriate data exist in cache?
       if ( isset($this->userCache[ $dataToGet ]) )
       {
           return $this->userCache[ $dataToGet ];//return the cached data, and forget about the DB queries
       }

   }

   //if we get here, caching was disabled or the required data has not yet been cached :(
   //all of my db querying would happen here

   //store the data that's just been fetched by the queries in the cache property

}
```

This way, I could call `getData( 'the data I want' , true );` whenever I want to fetch data from the DB, allowing me to use the cached data where and when possible.

So if I ever needed to call `getAccountInfo()`, `getStatusUpdates()` or `getFriendIDs()` multiple times, this method would prevent multiple DB queries being executed = good for scaling (I would think).

---

Comment: Where is the cached data persisted? If only in property - it almost makes no sense. There is a very little chance you perform the same request a lot during one page request. What makes more sense is to have some quick key-value storage (like memcached) and store the retrieved data there

Comment: Also - having `$useCache = true` is not a good design. Use caching decorator instead.

Comment: But different methods may need to fetch the same data. In this example, `getAccountInfo()` would need to fetch the same data as `getEmailAddress()`.

Comment: it doesn't worth it. If you want to cache data - use some persistent storage. Yes, keeping the data for further usage in the properties also may be a good to have, but real caching will bring significantly more to the overall performance. So from "scalability" point of view - your solution is almost pointless. So I would even may be agree with your teacher

Comment: @zerkms has a point, see my answer where I extend on what he is trying to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is silly :p

The main point I'd make is that this type of caching, depending on the context, can in fact be very helpful. I do this some in the web framework I've developed, and this refactoring has been driven by careful analysis of cachegrinds using XDebug.

Think about it this way. Your DB access is some of the most expensive (in terms of performance) work your PHP script will perform. It's easy to find pages where the DB-related calls are responsible for 50% (or more) of the total execution time of the page. Why not cache the results so any reuse of the data is automatically benefitting?

There's no reason not to in terms of PHP resource allocation, as under the covers, PHP will share the references to the zvals unless they're modified, so you're script won't require more memory on the heap, either.

For those who doubt this, I'd challenge them to run XDebug on a page that makes one DB call instead of two and to declare to the world that they can't see a significant result. When the code to implement this is so simple, why not make the improvement?

Now, some may point to more persistent forms of caching and say you should use them INSTEAD of this. I disagree with the universality implied by this type of response. Perhaps that data set is too large to cache on the server in entirety. For example, I'm not going to cache every persons data in memory when only 1% of the users login each day. It's not worth the memory on the server. Perhaps the data is updated frequently, in which case synchronizing becomes an issue/burden that can outweigh the benefits of caching. The point I'd make is that there are situations where more persistent forms of caching are not as appropriate.

Be green, every cycle counts :)

Comment: Great answer and glad you agree with me. Thanks xD

Comment: "Your DB access is some of the most expensive (in terms of performance) work your PHP script will perform." -- the issue is that OP doesn't share cache across the scripts, but only cache it per one call. So - it doesn't make much sense. It may give some improvements, but as @Mahn pointed out - only in *very specific* scenarios, while the persistent cache solution *always* works well.

Comment: "Now, some may point to more persistent forms of caching and say you should use them INSTEAD of this. " -- no one said to use it instead. But I said that persistent cache is what helps application scale, not this sort of cache.

Comment: "Perhaps the data is updated frequently, in which case synchronizing becomes an issue/burden that can outweigh the benefits of caching." --- right. The same with this caching solution.

Comment: PS: just to clear things out: I didn't downvote you, but I definitely not agree with several parts of your answer

Comment: The thing is, you don't NEED to manually cache every single person's data. If you implement your DB access correctly by using an ORM/DBAL, the caching can be taken care of by that piece of your code. Now when you retrieve an object, the model layer will look to see if the entity you're accessing is cached, and if it's not, will query the DB and cache. Consequently, only those objects which you actually use frequently will end up in the cache. So if only 1% of users log in every day, only that proportion will be in the cache.

Comment: Yes, an ORM/DBAL can abstract away some of this work, but it does come at a cost (just because you don't see the work being done doesn't mean it's not costing you something in terms of resources.) Knuth argues that apriori assessments of optimizations are frequently flawed, and assuming that the ORM/DBAL capabilities are ALWAYS beneficial is a mistake (I've benchmarked cases where I saved immensely in terms of resources by avoiding the ORM/DBAL in a manner that made more sense in a given context.)

Comment: @zerkms, A persistent cache scenario certainly does not always work (no optimization technique is always appropriate.)

Comment: @zerkms, 12% gains certainly do help you scale, and speaking to the simple example that was provided in the question, I've seen gains in similar code that approached or exceeded 12%.

Comment: @Adam: personally I do follow the presented technique, but never call it caching, just because performing the same query several times is a weird thing. PS: not sure where you get 12% from

Comment: I agree with Knuth as far as performance optimizations are concerned. But I see properly abstracted db access as optimising not for speed, but for maintainability/flexibility, and in that case it does make sense to think before you write it :)

Comment: @zerkms, You don't have to call it caching. My points have merely been that for a teacher to call this silly is foolish because people like you and I, ORM's, and many other tools in fact do this very thing. I like the number 12% because Knuth references it in one of his very early, seminal works (check it out if you haven't read it, great perspective on the go to statement, too :) http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf

Comment: @EzequielMuns, I'm not sure we'd agree on what properly abstracted db access looks like (I share Knuth's distaste for black boxes, which he expresses in Coders at Work.) In terms of maintainability, we agree, and I'd just point out that functional languages and/or AOP languages make the functionality listed above very easy to maintain and stay flexible.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it a bad idea?

Strictly speaking **it is not a bad idea *per se***, in that it will do you what you expect it to do and there is a little bit of performance to gain if you have duplicate queries in your script.

In practice, however, unless your script is doing something very, well, *unusual*, the number of database calls per request of your typical PHP script won't exceed 15 or 20, and out of those perhaps only 2 o 3 are duplicate tops. If the database calls were already relatively fast, haxing 2 or 3 database calls would have an **negligible** difference in performance. Not to mention the database itself may already have caching systems in place!

Implementing a persistent cache, one that lives between requests, is where the potential performance jackpot is, depending on your app/scripts.

**I'm not saying "don't do it"**, I'm just saying that unless you plan to run the same query hundreds of times within the same request/script, which is generally unlikely, you will not see much out of it without a persistent solution; but it will absolutely not hurt.

Comment: If a page is making 15 - 20 page requests, you have bigger issues. When the performance improvement is gauged against pages that make 2 - 4 DB requests (a much more common number) the result is significant (i.e., approaches the 12% improvement that people such as Donald Knuth say are worthwhile performance improvements.)

Comment: Algorithms aren't about hitting "the potential performance jackpot." When Dr. Knuth stated "premature optimization is the root of all evil", he did so in a context where he was addressing the issues with apriori assessment of optimization (which, anyone who questions the idea without testing would be guilty of.) Optimization is about finding meaningful (for me, I often shoot for 10% boosts in performance or greater, but you can pick whatever percentage improvement you want) and implementing them as you are able.

Comment: If you're making 2-4 DB requests per page and even two of them are *exactly the same* so that per-request caching will give you a performance gain, then you're definitely doing something wrong in your model layer.

Comment: You're assuming a model layer (there are many possible approaches to abstracting the DB calls, and I come from a functional programming background.) That said, if the model layer is performing this type of work, even if it's transparent to the user, then the model layer is doing the very thing the student suggested and this supports his case about the value of this type of caching.

Comment: @Adam, couple things. First, 15-20 database calls per request is perfectly normal for a relatively complex app, second, it's **not** the number of database calls what counts, but what they do. Just because one has less database calls in a script it does not mean there would be 12% improvement for haxing one of them; unless they are incredibly slow, in which case you've got other problems, removing 1 out of 4 database calls isn't going to give a noticeable performance improvement at all, specially if we are talking about duplicate queries. Go ahead and benchmark if you don't believe this.

Comment: Just for the record though, I did not downvote your answer, I respect your opinion.

Comment: @Mahn, Well, I doubt either of us could find data to support our claims on 15 - 20 database calls being normal or abnormal per page request. I've never built an app that required more than 6 DB calls on a particular page (and most of the time I'd work really hard to avoid even that many, 2 requests, even on my most complex apps, is more likely.) Now, in terms of the percentage increase of 12% (or more), I'm not speaking hypothetically here, I've actually benchmarked this. I've had real-world apps show a 12% improvement by refactoring the code to remove 1 of 3 or 4 existing calls...

Comment: @Adam but that depends on what were the queries doing, I'm pretty sure what you describe can happen, but categorically saying removing 1 out of 4 database calls will improve the performance by 12% is not correct.

Comment: @Mahn, cont... This depends on many factors. What type of persistence store is being used (MongoDB, MySQL, etc.) Where is the DB (same server or separate server.) Is the DB tuned for writes or reads? How many rows are in the DB? How many rows are required for the page request? How many joins are required? Etc... The point is that it there are many factors to consider. In a big DB that's on a separate server than the web server, I've seen (using PHP and XDebug) results where there was a 12% improvement by removing one query.

Comment: @Adam, right, my point is that removing 1 in 4 database calls will not always yield a 12% improvement, and *usually* it is not the case. For instance, if I had 4 queries like the following in a script: `SELECT * from users WHERE userID = 1`, removing one of them would get me nothing.

Comment: @Mahn, "...if I had 4 queries like the following in a script: SELECT * from users WHERE userID = 1, removing one of them would get me nothing." OK, I just tested this using my wordpress db on Rackspace Cloudsites (first with 4 SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE id = 1, then with 3, 2, 1.) Viewing the cachegrind, I see a 7% increase, 9% increase, 16% increase. And, I started PHP sessions and loaded my web framework (to increase PHP's work), and this occurred with really small, simple queries on a very small DB. In my opinion, these performance increases are not nothing.

Comment: @Adam, fine, you do have a point in that if the database is in a different machine you can save time by avoiding the round trips. I was thinking on scenarios were the database and the application shared the same machine; ie database and application performance leaving aside server trips.